# Modifying app.config file with Visual Studio Extension

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-addins, vspackage

I am trying to create a Visual Studio Extension (either Add-In or VSPackage) that will do the following:

1) Find all selected projects in the current solution.
2) Obtain access to each project's app.config or web.config file and modify it.

I have been able to figure out step 1 for both an Add-In and a VSPackage. I haven't managed to figure out a way to do step 2). Does anyone have pointers to a blog / documentation that can help me complete step 2) ?

Also, which extensibility option would you recommend for such a project? An Add-In or a VSPackage?

Thanks,

armahg

Comment: Any update on the plugin or maybe an alternative plugin?

Answer (score 3):

Since you have the selected projects, why just don't check if project directory has web.config/app.config files and if they exist then edit them? They are just xml files.

Comment: Hhmm I didn't think of that option. I was hoping there would be an API to do this with kind of like the AppSettings.Get, AppSettings.Set methods. I will try it though. Thanks.

Comment: ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437.aspx - this might help